# Installing clang 3.8 on Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: apt, aptitude, clang

I've tried the following obvious commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clang-3.8
```

but I get the message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo aptitude install clang-3.8
```

but get the message:

```
Couldn't find package "clang-3.8".  However, the following
packages contain "clang-3.8" in their name:
  clang-3.8-doc 
Couldn't find package "clang-3.8".  However, the following
packages contain "clang-3.8" in their name:
  clang-3.8-doc 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Hoping for a version of clang more recent than 3.5. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you please [edit] your question and include the output of  `apt-cache search clang`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looks like the latest version for 14.04.3 is [clang 3.6 in Trusty Updates](http://llvm.org/apt/). But the developers maintain a PPA which should get you the latest version:

[LLVM Debian/Ubuntu nightly packages](http://llvm.org/apt/)

To install 3.8 you would first add the key:

```
wget -O - http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
```

and then add the repository for 3.8 by adding the following line manually to `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or using the gui 'Software & Updates'):

```
deb http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.8 main
```

Screenshot here to demonstrate the technique:

[image]

Then run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clang-3.8 lldb-3.8
```

Test the installation as follows:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ clang-3.8 --version
clang version 3.8.0-svn262614-1~exp1 (branches/release_38)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
andrew@corinth:~$
```

And hopefully this will get you going...

Comment: As you can see at http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/dists/ only up to version 3.7 is available this way

Comment: Indeed, leave it with me and I shall approach the page owner. Hate to give bad advice so I will most definitely chase this down...

Comment: OK I have emailed Sylvestre and hopefully this issue can be resolved.

Comment: No answer yet :(

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've been busy with work for the past few days anyway, and this is just for a side-project so I'm not too worried. 3.6 works fine for now

Comment: Trying the site owner now.....

Comment: And now the cfe-dev mailing list: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2016-February/047565.html .

Comment: Finally the repository is fixed! I have updated my answer and tested it all: running well and clang 3.8 installs nicely...

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Impressed with your level of persistence with this

Comment: Some of it is my aggravation at myself for giving an answer without fully testing it out on my own computer, a lesson well learned :)

Comment: Wow, this is a new paradigm in Q&A, you first give an answer, and then make that answer come true :)

Comment: You can use `add-apt-repository` to add the repository without GUI and without editing the file manually. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1280073/87525) for an example.